# Regex for Google Analytics Code

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a set of URLs:

```
    /mobile.aspx?data=10&p=1
    /mobile.aspx?data=130&p=1
    /mobile.aspx?data=140&p=1
    /mobile.aspx?data=133&p=1
```

I have been trying to match them with the following 2 regular expressions:

```
    1) /mobile.aspx?data=(10|130|140|133)$&p=1
    2) ^/mobile\.aspx?data=(10|130|140|133)$&p=1
```

However, there is no match. What is wrong with these regular expressions?

Comment: I have formalized the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those, there are some issues with them. This one is correct:

```
 \/mobile\.aspx\?data=(\d+)&p=1. See regex101.com/r/hK9jR6/1
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hK9jR6/1).

The main issue was unescaped metacharacters `?` and `.`. Also, to capture multiple consecutive digits, you'd want to use `\d+` (any digit, 1 or more repetitions).